# aggregating data on the number of listview columns not fixed vb6

Tags: vb6

I have a problem to get the total of the contents in a listview if the number of columns is not fixed.

For example, I have 2 columns, A and B, where column A contains `1, 2, 3` and column B contains `4, 5, 6`. This can be solved with the following code:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim A, B As Double
Qty = 0
Dim ListItems As CLIST

Set CLIST = ListView2.ListItems.Add (,, "Grand Total")
For i = 1 to Listview1.ListItems.count
A = A + Listview1.ListItems (i). Subitems (1)
B = B + Listview1.ListItems (i). Subitems (2)

cList.Subitems (1) = A
cList.Subitems (2) = B
Next
```

This gives the result that the contents of A sum to 6 and the contents of B sum to 15.

This brings me back to my original question:
what if the number of columns is not fixed?
I've tried with the following code:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As ListItem
Dim A, B As Double
Qty = 0
Dim ListItems As CLIST

Set cList = ListView2.ListItems.Add (,, "Grand Total")
For i = 1 to Listview1.ListItems.count
For Each x In Listview1.Listitems
A = A + x.Subitems (1)
Next
cList.Subitems (i) = A
Next
```

But the result is not what I was expecting.

Comment: Could you please include some examples of how the second code doesn't work properly?

Comment: for the first code is not running correctly, but it should be known in advance many columns

and transform the latter result grandtotalnya one
example
A = 1, 2, 3 = 6
B = 4, 5, 6 = 15

if using a second code that result
A = 1, 2, 3 = 6
B = 4, 5, 6, = 13

Answer (score 0):

You want to have the inner loop on the sub items.

I used a for each for both the outer loop and the inner loop

```
For Each li In ListView1.ListItems
    For Each si In li.ListSubItems
        A = A + x.Subitems (1)
        'Add to your summary list view here
    Next si
Next li
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you @Rojo Orbalino, 
but has not been solved,
I mean here just want to get the grand total in each column on which listview column is not fixed.
if using code like this:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim A, B As Double
A = 0
B = 0
Dim List Items As CLIST
Set CLIST = ListView.ListItems.Add (,, "Grand Total")
For i = 1 to Listview1.ListItems.count
A = A + Listview1.ListItems (i). Subitems (1)
B = B + Listview1.ListItems (i). Subitems (2)
cList.Subitems (1) = A
cList.Subitems (2) = B
Next
```

we need to know the number of columns. but like where if the number of columns is not fixed?